# Duplicate first index of array in java application

Tags: java, arrays, json, constructor

I am creating a little utility program. In this program I am trying to assign an array to a Java Object like so: 
`new Food( name, state, arrayOfSymptoms, comment, isCategory)`, where arrayOfSymptoms is the array I have problems with.

When I send the content of the array to output log,  `[sym1, sym2, sym3, sym4]`.
However, after the construction is finished the array looks like this: `[sym1, sym1, sym2, sym3, sym4]`

Does someone know an easy way to fix this problem, or do I have to create a lot of extra code to delete and move indexes?

Thank you in advance!

Edit:

Code before constructor:

```
        Symptoms[] allSyms = new Symptoms[selSyms.size()];
        for (int j = 0; j < selSyms.size(); j++) {
            allSyms[j] = selSyms.get(j);
            System.out.println("CurrSym(" + j + "): " + allSyms[j]);
        }

        System.out.println("Amount of symptoms selected: " + allSyms.length);

        if(        // Basic Form Validation
                !nameField.getText().isEmpty()) {

            if (!isCategory.isSelected())
                MainController.makeLeaf(
                        MainController.categoryTitles.indexOf(categories.getValue()),
                        new Food(
                                nameField.getText(),
                                stateChoice.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(),
                                allSyms, // Symptoms Here
                                "",
                                false)
                );
        }
```

Creates the output shown here:

CurrSym(0): Name: Sym1, Comment: ""

CurrSym(1): Name: Sym2, Comment: ""

CurrSym(2): Name: Sym3, Comment: ""

CurrSym(3): Name: Sym4, Comment: ""

This clearly shows that the array only contains 4 elements.
However, when I convert the object into JSON, the output becomes as shown: 
`{"title": "Test Food", "state": 0, "symptoms":[{"name":"Sym1","comment":""},{"name":"Sym1","comment":""},{"name":"Sym2","comment":""},{"name":"Sym3","comment":""},{"name":"Sym4","comment":""}],"comment": "", "isCategory": false}`

The code to convert the object to JSON looks like this:

```
public String symptomsToJSON()
{
    String allSymptoms = "";

    if(getSymptoms() != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < symptoms.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0)
                allSymptoms += symptoms[i].toJSON();
            allSymptoms += "," + symptoms[i].toJSON();
        }
    }

    return allSymptoms;
}

public String toJSON()
{
    return "{\"title\": \"" + title + "\", \"state\": "+ state + ", \"symptoms\":[" + symptomsToJSON() + "],\"comment\": \"" + comment +"\", \"isCategory\": " + isCategory + "}";
}
```

Hope this new information helps!

Comment: Please show us the code.

Comment: You forgot about `else` after `allSymptoms += symptoms[i].toJSON();`. Otherwise `allSymptoms += "," + symptoms[i].toJSON();` will be always executed which includes when `i==0`. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Also concatenate new parts to String result in loop. This way you are creating in each iteration new string which first need to copy old one and then add new part to it. Use `StringBuilder` and `append` new parts to it.

Comment: Or better since Java 8 you can use `String.join(",", symptoms)` to get `sym0,sym1,...,symN`. You can also use `StringJoiner` instead of `StringBuilder` and set prefix to `[`, suffix to `]` and delimiter to `,`. Then `add` new elements to it and you will get `[element0,element1,element2]` so you will not need to handle that first `,`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an 'else' in symptomsToJSON():

```
public String symptomsToJSON() {
 String allSymptoms = "";
 if(getSymptoms() != null)   {
  for (int i = 0; i < symptoms.length; i++) {
      if (i == 0)
          allSymptoms += symptoms[i].toJSON();
      //NOTE: Without this,  the preceding line gets printed twice for i==0
      else 
          allSymptoms += "," + symptoms[i].toJSON();
    } 
 }
 return allSymptoms; 
}
```

``

Comment: *blush* So noob fail xD
Thanks a lot for your time!